# there was error connecting to http://localhost:3000/api/contact

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, postman

this is my mean code.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jet = require('jsonwebtoken');

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');


// retrieving Data
router.get('/contacts',(req,res,next)=>{
 // res.send('Retriving the contact list');
 console.log('contacts page');
Contact.find(function(err, contacts){
 res.json(contacts);
})
});

// to add the content 
router.post('/contact',(req, res, next)=>{
// logic to add contact
    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email_id: req.body.email_id,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    Contact.addRegistry((err, contacts)=> {
        if(err) {
            res.json({msg:'faild to add register'});
        }
        else{
            res.json({msg:'registry added sucessfully'});
        }

    });

});    
// to delete the content 
router.delete('/contact/:id',(req, res, next) =>{
    // logic to delete contact
    Contact.remove({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
    })    

module.exports = router;
```

the above file is route.js.
the below code is from contact.js

```
// Database code.
var express = require('express');
var app = express();     
var mongoose = require('mongoose');     
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');             



// database schaema  
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    id: String,
    location: String,
    profile_picture_url: String,
    email_id: String,
    phone: String,
    job_title: String,
    company: String,
    education: String,
    password: String,
     savedjobslist: {
        title: [],
        subtitle: []

     },
    appliedjobslist: {
        title: [],
        subtitle: []
    },
    failedjobslist: {
        title: [],
        subtitle: []
    }
});


const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema); 

module.exports.getUserById = function(id,callback) {
    Contact.findById(id,callback);
}
module.exports.getUserById = function(username,callback) {
    const query = {username: username}
    Contact.findOne(query,callback);
}
module.exports.addRegistry = function(newContact,callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newContact,salt, (err,hash) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
           newContact.password = hash;
           newContact.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to post the data from postman it is shoing the error as

> "there was error connecting to http://localhost:3000/api/contact"

and in the command prompt it is showing the error as

> Server started at port3000 connected to mongos database at 27017
>   Error: Illegal arguments: function, string
>       at _async (D:\project-1\back-end\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:214:46 )
>       at Object.bcrypt.hash (D:\project-1\back-end\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcry pt.js:220:13)
>       at bcrypt.genSalt (D:\project-1\back-end\models\contacts.js:49:16)
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (D:\project-1\back-end\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\ bcrypt.js:153:21)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5) D:\project-1\back-end\models\contacts.js:54
>              newContact.save(callback);
>                         ^
>
> TypeError: newContact.save is not a function
>       at bcrypt.hash (D:\project-1\back-end\models\contacts.js:54:23)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

newContact.save(callback);
            ^
TypeError: newContact.save is not a function.
i don't know why this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue here:

`bcrypt` for generating is throwing an error because of wrong parameters. You can't pass object (newContact) to `bcrypt`.

Try to generate a hash using the following code:

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
```

You can use [pre save function of mangoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to generate hashedPassword while storing this. Personally, I don't prefer as this adds new check everytime you save the object

Answer (score 0):

> find() takes query as an argument to search all pass {}

```
Contact.find({},function(err, contacts){
res.json(contacts);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Contact.addRegistry waits newContact as first parameter, but you do not pass it on your route.js

I think you want to do something like this

```
ContactSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const user = this;

  // generate a salt
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // hash your password
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      // store hash on the password field
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```